# TSQL selecting unique value from multiple ranges in a column

Tags: t-sql

A question from a beginner.

I have two tables. One (A) contains `Start_time, End_time, Status`. Second one (B) contains `Timestamp, Error_code`. Second table is automatically logged by system every few seconds, so it contains lots of non unique values of Error_code (it changes randomly, but within a time range from table A). What i need is to select unique error code for every time range (in my case every row) from the first table for every time range in table A:

A.Start_time, A.End_time B.Error_code.

I have come to this:

```
select A.Start_time,
       A.End_time,
       B.Error_code
from B
  inner join A
    on B.Timestamp between A.Start_time and A.End_time
```

This is wrong, i know.
Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If tour query gives a lot of duplicates use distinct to remove them:

```
select DISTINCT A.Start_time, A.End_time, B.Error_code
from B
inner join A on B.Timestamp between A.Start_time and A.End_time
```